# Why is post method not allowed when i write to a file in php?

Tags: php, html, forms, file-handling

so I'm new to php and I'm working on a school task. Its a simple form that will take the inputs and write it to a txt file. But for me it doesn't work. I tried to make a test version to see where the problem is and the error i get is 405 method not allowed. I have used fopen and fwrite too but they dont work too.

[image]

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="No">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index1</title>
</head>
<body>
 
  <form method="post" action="test21.php" name="myForm">
    klassekode <input type="text" id="klassekode" name="klassekode" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Fortsett" id="fortsett" name="fortsett" />
  </form>
 <a href="klasse.txt">Vis  klasser </a> 
               
</body> 
</html>
```

and my very simplified php code that i used to test test21.php

```
<?php
file_put_contents("klasse.txt", "test");
?>
```

Comment: "405 method not allowed" means you aren't allowed to make a POST request to that URL. The PHP isn't running so the problem has nothing to do with what you are asking about.

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed in this type of situation usually means, that the web server thinks the targeted file was "static", and therefor should not accept POST requests. Check that your web server is properly set up to execute PHP in files with the `.php` to begin with.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this is in any way related to the code within your PHP file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"405 method not allowed" means you aren't allowed to make a POST request to that URL.

Your screenshot shows that you are making the request to a server running on port 5500.

This is the default port for VS Code Live Server so I'm going to assume you are using that.

VS Code Live Server does not support PHP, or any form of server side programming, and will give 405 errors for POST requests.

You need to switch to an HTTP server that supports PHP. The [introduction page in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php) has some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a mis configuration of the web server. It reply `405` so it means that http method POST is not allowed by the server. You can see that `POST` is not in the `Allow:` header too.